# SWIG struct members are freed prematurely by Java's garbage collector

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, swig, finalizer

I have a C++ library that is called by Java through a SWIG-based interface. On the Java side, I build up a structure containing pointers to arrays of other structures, using the default struct interface and `carrays.i`'s `%array_class`.

Because Java's garbage collector is not aware of the members of the top-level struct, the array is sometimes freed, whereon its finalizer `delete[]`s its backing memory. I need a way around this, preferably without duplicating the struct in Java, since it's rather large.

A minimal example looks like this (although it probably won't trigger the bug since it doesn't do much):

C++/SWIG:

```
%module example

%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(object, objectArray);

struct object {
    unsigned int id;
    char *name;
};

struct data {
    size_t nobjects;
    object *objects;
};

void use_data(data*);
```

Java:

```
public class Example {
    private static data writeData() {
        data d = new data();
        objectArray os = new objectArray(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            object o = new object();
            o.setId(i);
            o.setName("obj" + i);
            os.setitem(i, o);
        }
        d.setNobjects(3);
        d.setObjects(os.cast());

        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        data d = writeData();
        example.use_data(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of possible solutions to this. The simplest is to wrap a function that can create `object`s without Java "owning" the memory. This might look something like:

```
%inline %{
object *new_object() {
  // SWIG will assume that it doesn't own this
  return new object;
}
%}
```

---

You can actually modify the `swigCMemOwn` `boolean` after creation. A typemap should be able to inject this at the appropriate place (when the `object` is handed to `setitem`). For example you could write:

```
%typemap(javacode) object %{
  object transfer() {
    swigCMemOwn = false;
    return this;
  }
%}
```

This needs to be before the `object` class is first seen and allows you to write something like:

```
os.setitem(i, o.transfer());
```

instead of `os.setitem(i, o);`.

---

A variation on this theme would be to use a `javain` typemap to replace the default `setitem` implementation in the Java proxy such that it calls a function (you supply) on the `object` to change the ownership, e.g.:

```
%javamethodmodifiers objectArray::setitem "protected";
%rename  objectArray::setitem setitemImpl;

%typemap(javacode) objectArray %{
  public void setitem(int i, object o) {
    o.disown();
    setitemImpl(i, o);
  }
%}
```

before the `%include "carrays.i"` and a corresponding `disown()` via `%typemap(javacode) object`. (`swigCMemOwn` is `protected`, so the `objectArray` can't modify that directly).

---

There are other approaches possible too, which involve setting the ownership also. The ones I've shown are the easiest I think though.

Alternatively, another common work around would be to [keep a reference to the Java proxy Object hanging around](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_memory_management_objects), by assigning it to a member variable. In this instance since you potentially have lots of objects that would have to be a container itself though.